# handling CodeIgniter routes errors?

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have a very simple route rules i used to put in the route configuration file within CodeIgniter .

```
$route['building/(:num)'] = 'building/$1';
```

the route rule working just fine with no issues the only problem i found that when passing a variable to the parameter it show this error message

```
An Error Was Encountered

The URI you submitted has disallowed characters.
```

i know my rule telling CodeIgniter to only accept numbers as parameters but what i need to do that in case of wrong parameters it must redirect to another defined page or url instead of showing this error.
i don't know if its possible to do it through configurations files or should i write a controller to do this
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Routes never sanitize or error-check the URI, they are there just to match a pattern. The error is generated because there are characters in the URI that are not present in the `$config['permitted_uri_chars']` setting in `application/config/config.php`, which is then being checked by the URI class in the `_filter_uri()` method.

Without knowing what the variable you're trying to use looks like (it apparently has URI-unfriendly characters), I would recommend validating and sanitizing those variables before attempting to use them in your URLs. **Especially** if they are user-generated. Don't trust people. Ever.

Some of your options include:

1. Sanitize / check your variable's value to see if it includes characters that are not supposed to be in your URIs. The default config setting is pretty much the norm for URI characters (though some others are permissible, too), so I'd try to stick to that if possible (especially if you don't know what you're doing).
2. Change your `permitted_uri_chars` list to include other characters (not really recommended, see #1).
3. Extend the URI class and replace / modify the `_filter_uri()` method, replacing the `show_error()` portion with a redirect or other code to suit your needs. Also not really recommended, since a library shouldn't be controlling your redirects.